# Why is thermostat calling for cool when set to heat

Tags: thermostat, heating, heat-pump

I have a White Rodgers 1F97-1277 thermostat. I set it to call for emergency (propane) heat on my York heat pump. Display shows 'Heat - Stage 1'. When I look at the furnace, no heat and no flame. The status light is blinking a slow amber, which is call for cool. This is not a new install.

My thoughts: Perhaps the cool is the defrost cycle for the heat pump (is that stage 1?). However, one would think if it can't meet the demand from the thermostat using the heat pump, it would turn to propane for heat. The amber light though means the furnace thinks the thermostat is calling for cool.

Why would the furnace show a call for cool, when the thermostat shows it's calling for heat.

Here is thermostat wiring:[image]

Here is the heat pump : [image]

Comment: Added pictures.

Comment: Its a YHE48B21SA

Comment: Did you happen to look at it when it was in defrost ? Some units don’t display defrost and they are not heating for the few minutes to defrost.

Comment: Perhaps but it doesn't change. It keeps slow blinking amber all day. No gas valve, flow or igniter action though. No warm air.

Comment: Has it worked in the past? Or is this new to you ? the e-heat should turn the gas on (if you have a pilot) or try to light the pilot not a standing pilot. Can you see the pilot or trying to light the pilot?

Comment: Worked in the past. It has an ignitor. So normally, the ignitor gets hot, gas valve opens and I have a flame. The ignitor never turns on.

Comment: Do you get the same symptoms if you set it to call for regular heat (vs. emergency heat)?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Its a little different. Main fan runs. Otherwise, inducer fan runs quite a bit. Just tested the pressure switch (removed wires) and it's open. Guessing it's supposed to be low resistance (< 5 ohms). Is that a fair assumption?

Comment: @asp316 -- so you don't get the slow blinking amber from the furnace when you set the thermostat to regular heat then?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I still get the slow blinking amber.

Comment: @asp316 -- can you measure the voltages at Y, W, and O/B coming from your thermostat (all relative to C) while you have it switched into 1) regular heat and 2) emergency heat mode?

Comment: Is your igniter a hot surface igniter or a spark type? It is not uncommon for hot surface igniters to fail, if you are not getting ignition it could be that as you have checked your pressure sensors.

Comment: After watching the entire cycle, it would blink amber, fault, blink 3 red a couple times ( about 15 second window), go back to blinking amber and try again. I never saw the 3 red until I watched the entire cycle. Pressure switch error. So I tested it and it was intermittent. Replaced it and the furnace started. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

The OP posted his answer in a comment. Moving it here to make it more discoverable.

> After watching the entire cycle, it would blink amber, fault, blink 3 red a couple times ( about 15 second window), go back to blinking amber and try again. I never saw the 3 red until I watched the entire cycle. Pressure switch error. So I tested it and it was intermittent. Replaced it and the furnace started.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is that the the wires are hooked up incorrectly.

Pop the cover on the thermostat and look at the labeling where the wire to the furnace attaches.

Do the same at the furnace end.

This may make it clear.

Second step:  Check the installation manuals for the furnace and the thermostat.  If you have 12v control for the heat pump, and the furnace wants a 24v signal...

Third:  It may be that the thermostat cannot properly control two devices.  In this case install a second thermostat at a point that is both reasonably central, and easy to run wire to the furnace.

Comment: Based on OPs comments (not in the original question), this is not a new install and it's been working. Sounds more like failed parts. Unless, of course, the evil HVAC elves have been into his house and rewired things in the middle of the night. ;)

Comment: It's almost always elves.  Except when it's house goblins.